# Customize SeekBar with two thumb in Android

Tags: android, seekbar

I use a seekbar with two thumb in my application and would like to customize it.

I want to change the drawable(I want to use my own image). How to do it?
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Basically you will need Range Bar. User can set Range between two numbers

Check this lib - https://github.com/oli107/material-range-bar

Above library is also supports Material design which provides rich UI

Hope it will help :)